# APEX: Item is blank when trying to prepopulate with value

Tags: oracle-apex

My Scenario:

I have a report on page 1 which has a link to page 2. This link passes an ID to page 2 (`V2_ID` gets set with `V1_ID`).

I then have two items called `V2_ID` and `V2_NAME` on page 2, as well as a PL/SQL process on page 2 which executes after the header loads which

```
select name into :V2_NAME from table where id = :V_ID;
```

The `V2_ID` shows the value, but the `V2_NAME` is always blank.

How can I pre-populate this variable. This is a very simple example as my use case is much more complicated, but the concept is the same. I can't use automatic row fetch because each item comes from a different table (it is a horrible database design, but I have to work with it).

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

If on page 2 you have a PL/SQL process at the process point='On Load - After Header' and the procedure looks something like this:

```
Begin
select name into :V2_NAME from table where id =:V2_ID;
end;
```

and no condition on it then it should work.

Check that `:V2_NAME` does not have Source Type= Always NULL;

Comment: What should the source type be?

Comment: You can put Source Used="Only when current value in session is null" and Source Type="Static Assignment".

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if Im wrong, from what ive understood, only one value is passed from page 1 to page 2 which is V1_ID to V2_ID,right?then on page 2, you have a process that will execute after the header loads and that is

```
SELECT name 
INTO :V2_NAME 
FROM TABLE 
    WHERE id = :V_ID
```

Is the :V_ID a typo?It should be :V2_ID,if its not maybe its the cause as to why :V2_NAME doesnt give you a value.
Instead of having a process after header, why dont you just put the query in the item SOURCE, choose type: QUERY, used: ALWAYS, REPLACE ANY EXISTING VALUES ON SESSION STATE.
then in the query box, put

```
SELECT name 
FROM TABLE 
    WHERE id = :V2_ID
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The variables I use here are just simplified of my actual application. In my actual application I have just over 60 fields. If I put the query individually on each field then it works, the problem is this send over 60 select statement to my database which kills my performance. Int he process it is just one Select statement which inserts into all 60 fields.

Comment: oh i see.cant you show us the actual query just to make sure if you havent miss anything?